# Getting Multilinestring Z to stand on background using Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, linestring, 3d-map, extrude

I added to Mapbox, a 3D not extruded object by geojson: a Linestring Z. However, it's stand on the background.

Is it possible to put this object at the height that is defined?

Answer (score 1):

Not implemented yet see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3993.

deck.gl does support this currently.